# SPD Preconditioner

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I'm studying stuff about preconditioning and I understood that the idea behind is that, if I want to solve linear system

$$ A\textbf{x} = \textbf{b} $$

where $A$ is Symmetric Positive Definite $n \times n$ Matrix, I can pre-multiply it by $M^{-1}$ in such a way

$$(M^{-1}A)\textbf{x}=M^{-1}\textbf{b} $$

so that $k_2(M^{-1}A)\lt \lt k_2(A)$. Why this happens when $M^{-1}A \approx A^{-1}$?

Also, should I impose that my preconditioner is SPD too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood two points. A good preconditioner is a matrix $M$ such that $M$ is nonsingular, $M^{-1}$ is a good approximation of $A^{-1}$ and such that any linear system $Mx=f$ can be solved rapidly. In this case, we have that $M^{-1}A \approx I$ is a good approximation. Now, when $A$ is symmetric positive definite we frequently search for a preconditioner $M$ which is symmetric positive definite and such that $L^{-1}AL^{-T}$ is a good approximation of the identity transformation, where $M = LL^T$ is the Cholesky factorization of $M$. If $$k_2(L^{-1}AL^{-T}) \ll k_2(A)$$ then the preconditioned conjugate gradient algorithm with preconditioner $M = LL^T$ will converge more rapidly than the conjugate gradient algorithm with no preconditioning. A good first choice for $M$ can sometimes be obtained by computing the incomplete Cholesky factorization of $A$.

Comment: ok but why do we search for a preconditioner that is SPD too? I understood that if the matrix is sparse it would be nice to have a spase precondtitioner in order to reduce the matrices products computational costs, right?

Comment: @JamesArten If $A$ is SPD, then so is $A^{-1}$. When we seek a good approximation of $A^{-1}$ it is a sound strategy to mirror the properties of the target. We do not necessarily care about the cost of computing the action of $M$, i.e., matrix vector product of the form $y = Mx$, we care about the cost of solving linear systems of the form $Mx=b$. If $A$ is very large, then we almost certainly do not have the memory to store a dense matrix $M$ and a sparse preconditioner might be all we can afford.